# Are there any way to modify the devTools.css of Chrome Dev Tool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The font size of Chrome Developer Tools is too small. I have to modify the devTools.css every time I open the Developer Tool.

Are there any way to modify the devTools.css and save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can tweak the `Custom.css` file in the `User StyleSheets` directory in your [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

- Here's a blog post about doing that:
  http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/
- Or just run chrome://version in your chrome address bar.

Then add the following to increase the font size: http://dpaste.com/hold/599668/

Comment: and also if you like black background use my gist https://gist.github.com/1249280

Comment: Too bad devtools isn't built for a custom font-size. My min font-size is 18px and devtools is completely messed up. Need 200+ lines of Custom.css CSS to fix that.

Comment: Blog link is dead ... any newer guides?